# what is the range of the Ruby Date or DateTime object?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

what is the earliest and latest date that can be represented by a Ruby Date or DateTime object?

More specifically is the range greater or less than that of a Javascript Date object (1970 +/- 285,616 years)

Comment: Should help: http://stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.in/2010/07/limits-of-time-in-ruby.html

Comment: thanks - I couldn't find anything through google

Answer (score 2):

Ruby Date and DateTime classes store the offset from their reference date as a [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Rational.html) and as such are unbounded.

The Time class is usually limit to the unix epoch +/- either 2^31 or 2^63 seconds (depending on whether you are on a 64 bit platform)

Comment: Thanks - my simple minded trial and error approach would have taken forever!